# JSF Updating values in a bean from a list

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

So, I have a session scoped bean that has a 2 lists of string values. This bean is called AgreementBean.java. I'm showing these lists in a page called agreementDetail.xhtml like this

```
<h:dataTable id="servers" value="#{agreement.licenseServerNames}" var="licenseServerName">
                        <h:column>
                            <h:inputText value="#{licenseServerName}"/>
                        </h:column>
                    </h:dataTable>
                    Computer IDs<br/>
                    <h:dataTable id="idNames" value="#{agreement.computerIdNames}" var="computerIdName">    
                        <h:column>
                            <h:inputText value="#{computerIdName}"/>
                        </h:column>
                    </h:dataTable>
```

As you can see, I expect user input on these values. I need to make an Ajax call to update those values when the customer clicks on a "Save button". Here's the button's jsf code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
                        function showAlert(data){                          
                                 alert("SAVED!");   
                        }
                    </script>
                    <h:commandButton value="Save" immediate="true" type="submit" action="#{agreement.save}">
                        <f:ajax onevent="showAlert"/>
                    </h:commandButton><br/><br/>
```

The "Save" bean method does nothing right now, except for logging the values stored in both lists. 
When clicking on the button, 2 things are happening right now. If the customer changed the values on the inputFields, the bean's list's value is set to null. If the customer didn't change anything, then the bean's original value is kept.

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are 2 problems with your command button:

```html
<h:commandButton value="Save" immediate="true" type="submit" action="#{agreement.save}">
    <f:ajax onevent="showAlert"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

1. `immediate="true"` causes that **only** input elements which *also* have `immediate="true"` set will be processed. However, your inputs don't have this attribute set.
2. `<f:ajax execute>` defaults to `@this`, causing that **only** the command button itself is processed during form submit. Your inputs are therefore skipped in processing.

Get rid of the misplaced attribute and tell `<f:ajax>` to execute the entire form.

```html
<h:commandButton value="Save" type="submit" action="#{agreement.save}">
    <f:ajax execute="@form" onevent="showAlert"/>
</h:commandButton>
```

#### See also:

- [Why was "immediate" attribute added to the EditableValueHolders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071512/why-was-immediate-property-added-to-the-editablevalueholders)

---

Then there's a potential problem with your data model. You seem to be supplying a `List<String>` to the data table instead of a `List<SomeBean>`. The `String` is immutable and doesn't have a setter for the value. A `<h:inputText value="#{string}">` is never going to work. For the first table, you really need to have a `LicenseServer` bean with a `private String name` property. You can then use it as follows:

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{agreement.licenseServers}" var="licenseServer">
    <h:column>
        <h:inputText value="#{licenseServer.name}"/>
```

#### See also:

- [Why input (for example h:inputText) nested in h:dataTable do not update Bean model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628778/why-input-for-example-hinputtext-nested-in-hdatatable-do-not-update-bean-mod/4628828#4628828)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, are you aware that `onevent` is invoked 3 times? For the purpose you'd probably like to check if ajax event status equals to `"success"`.

#### See also:

- [Proccess onclick function after ajax call <f:ajax>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13540298/proccess-onclick-function-after-ajax-call-fajax/13540905#13540905)

Comment: You are spot on on the onevent thing... I'll fix that pretty soon, thanks! Also, now, something weird is going on when clicking the button. Instead of updating the list values, it's adding the original value twice to the list. So, instead of changing <original> to <new>, the list has <original, original>. Ideas?

Comment: Hard to tell based on the code provided so far. It's too much oversimplified that it wouldn't work at all. You should have something like `<h:inputText value="#{row.property}">` and not  `<h:inputText value="#{property}">`.

Comment: The thing is that it's a list handled by a dataTable. The property is the list itself, not the values contained in it, and those values are the inputText fields. :/ (Sorry if I'm bothering you... I'm new to JSF)

Comment: I didn't mean that. You seem to have a `List<String>` instead of a `List<LicenseServer>`. Strings are immutable and it's impossible to update the values this way. If that's the *real* code, then well, you got there another cause.

Comment: Ok, I'll try to find another way to handle inputFields on string lists. Google time! Thanks for your help, sir!